# Select into a 2D array

Tags: sql, database, arrays, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, how can I select some values into a 2D array?

For example, if I want to aggregate a field of data into an array, I would use the ARRAY() constructor or array_agg function e.g.

```
ARRAY(SELECT s.name FROM myschema.mytable s)
```

How would I go about selecting say, two values, into a 2D array i.e.

```
2DARRAYFUNCTION(SELECT s.name, s.id FROM ...)
```

Comment: Yep :) The problem is really coming from the fact that my postgreSQL to C# data reading library (NPGSQL) really has no way of easily intreperetting the data I'm trying to pull back (nested types or rows of the 'record' pseudotype). Hence trying key-value pairs, array of arrays, 2D arrays etc.

Comment: Obviously a follow up to this one: stackoverflow.com/q/9129855/939860

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to aggregate an `ARRAY` (build from key and value like in your example) into a two-dimensional array, the aggregate function `array_agg()` or the `ARRAY` constructor error out:

I happen to have written an [answer for this case *exactly*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134316/939860) recently. Turns out, it's your prequel question.

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation [HERE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html).