# Selecting data into a Postgres array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the following data:

```
name          id             url

John          1              someurl.com
Matt          2              cool.com
Sam           3              stackoverflow.com
```

How can I write an SQL statement in Postgres to select this data into a multi-dimensional array, i.e.:

```
{{John, 1, someurl.com}, {Matt, 2, cool.com}, {Sam, 3, stackoverflow.com}}
```

I've seen this kind of array usage before in Postgres but have no idea how to select data from a table into this array format.

Assuming here that all the columns are of type `text`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot use `array_agg()` to produce multi-dimensional arrays, at least not up to PostgreSQL 9.4.
(But the upcoming **Postgres 9.5** ships a [new variant of `array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) that can!)

What you get out of [@Matt Ball's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762483/939860) is an array of records (`the_table[]`).

An array can only hold elements of the same base type. You obviously have number and string types. Convert all columns (that aren't already) to `text` to make it work.

You can create an aggregate function for this like I demonstrated to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134316/939860) before.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray)  (
    SFUNC     = array_cat
   ,STYPE     = anyarray
   ,INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

Call:

```
SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[ARRAY[name, id::text, url]]) AS tbl_mult_arr
FROM   tbl;
```

Note the additional `ARRAY[]` layer to make it a multidimensional array (2-dimenstional, to be precise).

Instant demo:

```
WITH tbl(id, txt) AS (
    VALUES
      (1::int, 'foo'::text)
     ,(2,      'bar')
     ,(3,      '}b",') -- txt has meta-characters
    )
    , x AS (
    SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[ARRAY[id::text,txt]]) AS t
    FROM   tbl
    )
SELECT *, t[1][3] AS arr_element_1_1, t[3][4] AS arr_element_3_2
FROM   x;
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use an [aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html); `array_agg` should do what you need.

```
SELECT array_agg(s) FROM (SELECT name, id, url FROM the_table ORDER BY id) AS s;
```

Comment: This answer returns an array of records, not a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Yes - just got in working in context and you're right... I really need the multi-dimensional array!

Comment: @MattW: I think you can be helped. :) Posted an answer.