# Value Assignment of multidimensional array fails in PL/PGSQL

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array, plpgsql

I'm trying to materialize the content of a table into a multidimensional array in PL/PGSQL.

(Just for those who are wondering what the 'neighbors' are: The tables wnode and wedge define a graph with nodes `wnode` and edges `wedge`. Now I want to store the neighbors of a node v in an array contained in `neighbors[v]`).

This is what I've done so far:

```
DECLARE
    neighbors INTEGER[][];
    v INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR v IN SELECT n_id FROM wnode LOOP
        SELECT ARRAY ( SELECT n2_id FROM wedge WHERE n1_id=v) INTO neighbors[v];
    END LOOP;

    RETURN neighbors;
```

The preceding code fails due to a syntax error:

```
ROW 7: ...( SELECT n2_id FROM wedge WHERE n1_id=v) INTO neighbors[v];
                                                                 ^
```

The next thing I tried was introducing a backing variable `tmp`:

```
DECLARE
    neighbors INTEGER[][];
    v INTEGER;
    tmp INTEGER[];
BEGIN
    FOR v IN SELECT n_id FROM wnode LOOP
        SELECT ARRAY ( SELECT n2_id FROM wedge WHERE n1_id=v) INTO tmp;
        neighbors[v] := tmp;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN neighbors;
END
```

I got this runtime error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: »{140,153,290,360,393}«
```

I also tried using `SELECT array_append(neighbors, tmp) INTO neighbors;` without any success.

I'm out of ideas right now. What I'd try next is iterate through `tmp` and assign each value `neighbors[v][i] := tmp[i];`... not really elegant.

I'd like to know how I can fill my multidimensional array in a more elegant way? (Maybe it is possible by using a single SQL-Query only?).

Thanks for your help. :-)

EDIT: [Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1afe8)

Comment: Please provide your table definitions and some sample data, ideally in an sqlfiddle. Random example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1ab81/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can probably be solved rather easily with the aggregate function outlined under this related question:
[Selecting data into a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762398/selecting-data-into-a-postgres-array-format)

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray)  (
    SFUNC     = array_cat
   ,STYPE     = anyarray
   ,INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

Guess (since table definitions are missing):

```
SELECT INTO neighbors 
       array_agg_mult(ARRAY[e_arr]) AS mult_arr
FROM  (
   SELECT array_agg(n2_id) AS e_arr
   FROM   wedge
   GROUP  BY n1_id
   ORDER  BY n1_id
   ) e;
```

#### Update

You have to add an array-layer to make it a 2d-array.
Note that all 1D-arrays have to share the same length, or the query will error out.

[->sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/97550/3) to demonstrate both.

Comment: Surprisingly, this won't work neither. The output I get is a one-dimensional array containing all n2_id's ever computed during the query execution. I'm starting to think, that this might be a bug in pl/pgsql

Comment: @Simon: Not a bug, just a missing array layer in my untested prototype. Fixed.