# postgresql: Aggregating arrays of text

Tags: postgresql

I want to get an array of all words associated with each `id` in this example data:

```
id | words
---|------------------
1  | {foo,bar,zap,bing}
2  | {foo}
1  | {bar,zap}
2  | {bing}
1  | {bing}
2  | {foo,bar}
```

Outputs:

```
id | allwords
---|--------------------------------
1  | {foo,bar,zap,bing,bar,zap,bing}
2  | {foo,bing,foo,bar}
```

I tried using `array_agg(words)` but it yields:

`ERROR:  could not find array type for data type text[]`

What's the proper approach here? I want all words, even the duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array_agg` collects the results of a column into an array; it doesn't aggregate arrays.

[`array_cat`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html) is the functionality you want, but it isn't an aggregate function.

To define your own aggregate based on it, use this code:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_cat_aggregate (anyarray)  (
    SFUNC     = array_cat
   ,STYPE     = anyarray
   ,INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

which I blatantly copied from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763245/1394393. (I don't think the question is a duplicate.)

Pretending the table is called `temp`, then you can select using the function with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT id, array_cat_aggregate(words)
FROM temp
GROUP BY id;
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7c828/1/0

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to jpmc26 solution you can also combine `array_agg` with a subquery that `unnest` your arrays:

```
SELECT id, array_agg(w) AS allwords
FROM
(
  SELECT
   id,
   unnest(words) AS w
  FROM words_table
) x
GROUP BY id;
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5c8c9/13/0)

Comment: I would like to note that this answer extends to reducing the array to unique values better than mine. One need only add `DISTINCT` like so: `array_agg(DISTINCT w)`.