# Cumulative array from previous rows array?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, window-functions

Is there a query that would merge previous arrays into a cumulative array, that would result in:

```
id array_field   c_array
---------------------------------------------
1  {one,two}     {one,two}
2  {three}       {one,two,three}
3  {four,five}   {one,two,three,four,five}
4  {six}         {one,two,three,four,five,six}
```

Comment: I am happy you accepted my answer, but in this case answer provided by Erwin is much better from my point of view. Is there any reason why you accepted mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you work with. Seems like your base table holds text arrays `text[]`.

- You can use any aggregate function as window function. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html)

> In addition to these functions, any built-in or user-defined aggregate
>   function can be used as a window function

- There is `array_agg()` but it operates on scalar types, *not* on array types.
- But you can [create your own aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createaggregate.html) easily.

To aggregate array types, create this aggregate function:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray)  (
    SFUNC     = array_cat
   ,STYPE     = anyarray
   ,INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

Details in this related answer:
[Selecting data into a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762398/selecting-data-into-a-postgres-array-format/11763245#11763245)

Now, the job is strikingly simple:

```
SELECT array_agg_mult(array_field) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS result_array
FROM   tbl
```

Since the aggregate is defined for [polymorphic types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC), this works for *any array type*, not just `text[]`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cef14/2) including alternative solution for text representation in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/75fe3/2)

Data:

```
-- drop table if exists sample_data;
create table sample_data (id int, arr varchar[]);

insert into sample_data
  values
    (1,ARRAY['One','Two','Three']),
    (2,ARRAY['Four','Six']),    
    (3,ARRAY['Seven']);
```

Query:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select 
    id, arr, arr as merged_arr 
  from 
    sample_data
  where
    id = 1

  union all

  select 
    sd.id, sd.arr, cte.merged_arr || sd.arr
  from
    cte
    join sample_data sd on (cte.id + 1  = sd.id)
)

select * from cte
```

Result:

```
1;{One,Two,Three};{One,Two,Three}
2;{Four,Six};     {One,Two,Three,Four,Six}
3;{Seven};        {One,Two,Three,Four,Six,Seven}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `UPDATE` with a CTE that refers back to the previous id:

```
WITH prev AS (SELECT id, c_array AS prev_array FROM your_table)
UPDATE your_table
SET c_array = prev_array || array_field
FROM prev
WHERE id = prev.id + 1;
```

If you want to do this automatically, then you need a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and in the trigger function you simply execute `SELECT c_array || NEW.array_field INTO NEW.c_array FROM your_table WHERE id = NEW.id - 1` if - and only if - you set the id yourself. If the id comes from a sequence then you need an `AFTER INSERT` trigger with an update as described above.