# Calculating follower growth over time for each influencer

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with influencers and their follower counter for each day:

```
influencer_id |     date     |    followers
     1        | 2020-05-29   |      7361
     1        | 2020-05-28   |      7234
                    ...
     2        | 2020-05-29   |       82
     2        | 2020-05-28   |       85
                    ...
     3        | 2020-05-29   |      3434
     3        | 2020-05-28   |      2988
     3        | 2020-05-27   |      2765
                    ...
```

Let's say I want to calculate how many followers each individual influencer has gained in the last 7 days and get the following table:

```
influencer_id |                       growth
     1        |  <num followers last day - num followers first day>
     2        |                         "
     3        |                         "
```

As a first attempt I did this:

```
SELECT influencer_id,
      (MAX(followers) - MIN(followers)) AS growth
FROM influencer_follower_daily
WHERE date < '2020-05-30'
AND date >= '2020-05-23'
GROUP BY influencer_id;
```

This works and shows the growth over the week for each influencer. But it assumes the follower count always increases and people never unfollow!

So is there a way to achieve what I want using an SQL query over the original table? Or will I have to generate a completely new table using a `FOR` loop that calculates a +/- follower change column between each date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple aggregate functions `first()` and `last()` are not implemented in standard Postgres. But see below.

### 1. `array_agg()`

[Gordon demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62156385/939860) a query with **`array_agg()`**, but that's more expensive than necessary, especially with many rows per group. Even more so when called twice, and with `ORDER BY` per aggregate. This equivalent alternative should be **substantially faster**:

```
SELECT influencer_id, arr[array_upper(arr, 1)] - arr[1]
FROM  (
   SELECT influencer_id, array_agg(followers) AS arr
   FROM  (
      SELECT influencer_id, followers
      FROM   influencer_follower_daily
      WHERE  date >= '2020-05-23'
      AND    date <  '2020-05-30'
      ORDER  BY influencer_id, date
      ) sub1
   GROUP  BY influencer_id
   ) sub2;
```

Because it sorts *once* and aggregates *once*. The sort order of the inner subquery `sub1` is carried over to the next level. See:

- [How to apply ORDER BY and LIMIT in combination with an aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213724/3684)

**Indexes** matter:

- If you query the whole table or most of it, an **index** on `(influencer_id, date, followers)` can help (a lot) with index-only scans.
- If you query only a small fragment of the table, an **index** on `(date)` or `(date, influencer_id, followers)` can help (a lot).

### 2. `DISTINCT` & window functions

Gordon also demonstrated `DISTINCT` with window functions. Again, can be **substantially faster**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (influencer_id)
       influencer_id
     , last_value(followers) OVER (PARTITION BY influencer_id ORDER BY date
                                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
     - followers AS growth
FROM   influencer_follower_daily
WHERE  date >= '2020-05-23'
AND    date <  '2020-05-30'
ORDER  BY influencer_id, date;
```

With a *single* window function, using the same sort order (!) as the main query. To achieve this, we need the non-default window definition with `ROWS BETWEEN ...` See:

- [PostgreSQL query with max and min date plus associated id per row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9800/3684)

And `DISTINCT ON` instead of `DISTINCT`. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

### 3. Custom aggregate functions

#### `first()` and `last()`

You can add those yourself, it's pretty simple. See [instructions in the Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)).
Or install the [additional module `first_last_agg`](https://pgxn.org/dist/first_last_agg/) with a faster implementation in C.

Related:

- [Use something like TOP with GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934741/use-something-like-top-with-group-by/43937668#43937668)

Then your query becomes simpler:

```
SELECT influencer_id, last(followers) - first(followers) AS growth
FROM  (
   SELECT influencer_id, followers
   FROM   influencer_follower_daily 
   WHERE  date >= '2020-03-02'
   AND    date <  '2020-05-09'
   ORDER  BY influencer_id, date
   ) z
GROUP  BY influencer_id
ORDER  BY influencer_id;
```

#### Custom aggregate `growth()`

You can combine `first()` and `last()` in a single aggregate function. That's faster, but calling two C functions will still outperform one custom SQL function.

Basically encapsulates the logic of my first query in a custom aggregate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_growth(anyarray)
  RETURNS anyelement LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
'SELECT $1[array_upper($1, 1)] - $1[1]';

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE growth(anyelement) (
   SFUNC     = array_append
 , STYPE     = anyarray
 , FINALFUNC = f_growth
 , PARALLEL  = SAFE
);
```

Works for any numeric type (or any type with an operator `type - type` returning the same type). The query is simpler, yet:

```
SELECT influencer_id, growth(followers)
FROM  (
   SELECT influencer_id, followers
   FROM   influencer_follower_daily 
   WHERE  date >= '2020-05-23'
   AND    date <  '2020-05-30'
   ORDER  BY influencer_id, date
   ) z
GROUP  BY influencer_id
ORDER  BY influencer_id;
```

Or a little slower, but ultimately short:

```
SELECT influencer_id, growth(followers ORDER BY date)
FROM   influencer_follower_daily 
WHERE  date >= '2020-05-23'
AND    date <  '2020-05-30'
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c05eb8745fe668bb088d5290229cc87f)*

### 4. Performance optimization for *many* rows per group

With *many* rows per group / partition, other query techniques can be (a lot) faster. Techniques along these lines:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

If that applies, I suggest you start a new question disclosing exact table definition(s) and cardinalities ...

---

Closely related:

- [Get values from first and last row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170215/get-values-from-first-and-last-row-per-group/25173081#25173081)
- [PostgreSQL: joining arrays within group by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557344/postgresql-joining-arrays-within-group-by-clause/24560018#24560018)
- [Use something like TOP with GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934741/use-something-like-top-with-group-by/43937668#43937668)
- [Best performance in sampling repeated value from a grouped column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134657/best-performance-in-sampling-repeated-value-from-a-grouped-column/36222951#36222951)

Comment: @ddriver1: I would be interested in the relative performance for the provided queries. Could you run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)` with each (best of 5 to level caching artifacts) and add an answer? (Plus table & index definition and cardinalities if that's not too much to ask.)

Comment: Many thanks for the incredibly detailed answer. The table has indexes on columns ID and influencer_id, which is a FK to a separate influencer table. The other columns are followers and day. 

I did a best of 10 for each of the queries you provided. They all produced the correct result and sorted 66293 rows at some point.

Comment: Here are the results:

1. array_agg(): 103.2ms
2. Distinct+window: 137.1ms
3. first() and last() using portable SQL (not C): 256.3ms
4. custom aggregate growth(): 166.8ms 

(5. Gordon's distinct+window: 284.4ms)

Comment: @ddriver1: Thanks for coming back with test results! Much like I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't have a `first()`/`last()` aggregation function.  One method is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT influencer_id,
       ( FIRST_VALUE(followers) OVER (PARTITION BY influencer_id ORDER BY DATE DESC) -
         FIRST_VALUE(followers) OVER (PARTITION BY influencer_id ORDER BY DATE ASC)
       ) as growth
FROM influencer_follower_daily
WHERE date < '2020-05-30' AND date >= '2020-05-23';
```

Another alternative is to use arrays:

```
SELECT influencer_id,
       ( ARRAY_AGG(followers ORDER BY DATE DESC) )[1] -
         ARRAY_AGG(followers ORDER BY DATE ASC) )[1]
       ) as growth
FROM influencer_follower_daily
WHERE date < '2020-05-30' AND date >= '2020-05-23'
GROUP BY influencer_id;
```

Comment: This works! By the way, you added an accidental minus (-) symbol after DATE ASC) in the first query. I tried to edit it but the edit is too small.