# appending to multi dimensional arrays in postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array, aggregate-functions

I am trying to create a multi-column aggregate function that needs to accumulate all the column values for later processing.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION accumulate_scores(prev integer[][],l1 integer,
l2 integer,l3 integer) RETURNS integer[][] AS
$$      
BEGIN  
prev[1] = array_append(prev[1],l1);
prev[2] = array_append(prev[2],l2);
prev[3] = array_append(prev[3],l3);
return prev;
END 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE AGGREGATE my_aggregate(integer,integer,integer)(
 SFUNC  = accumulate_scores,
 STYPE     = integer[][],
 INITCOND  = '{}'  
);

select accumulate_scores(ARRAY[1]|| ARRAY[[1],[1]],2,3,4);
```

I get this error

```
ERROR: function array_append(integer, integer) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How do i accumulate these values into a multi dimensional array?

Edit: i have tried with array_cat and get the same error. thought array_append might be right since prev[1] is a uni dimensional array

Comment: I believe it is because array_append takes array, element as parameters, and the prev[1] in array_append(prev[1],l1) is not an array but a value.

Comment: I think you need to use array_cat for multidimensional array, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/arrays.html. What are you hoping for as an end result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You function & aggregate function would "work" like this, but it would only create a 1-dimenstional array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION accumulate_scores(prev integer[][]
                                            ,l1 integer
                                            ,l2 integer
                                            ,l3 integer)
  RETURNS integer[][] AS
$func$
BEGIN 
prev := prev || ARRAY[l1,l2,l3];

RETURN prev;
END 
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE AGGREGATE my_aggregate(integer,integer,integer)(
 SFUNC     = accumulate_scores,
 STYPE     = integer[][],
 INITCOND  = '{}'  
);
```

The declaration `RETURNS integer[][]` is equivalent to just `RETURNS integer[]`. For Postgres all arrays on the same base element are the *same* type. Additional brackets are for documentation only and ignored.

To actually produce a **multi-dimensional array**, you don't need a custom function. Just a custom aggregate function:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray)  (
    SFUNC     = array_cat
   ,STYPE     = anyarray
   ,INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

Then you can:

```
SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[ARRAY[l1,l2,l3]])  -- note the two array layers!
from   tbl;
```

More details here:

- [Selecting data into a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762398/selecting-data-into-a-postgres-array-format/11763245#11763245)

Comment: Thanks. I used approach 2 to get a multi-dimensional array which i process in the final function of my aggregate into multiple single arrays on which i can do further math

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand the question

```
select array[
    array_agg(l1),
    array_agg(l2),
    array_agg(l3)
]
from (values
    (1, 9, 1, 2, 3), (2, 9, 4, 5, 6)
) s(id, bar, l1, l2, l3)
group by bar;
        array        
---------------------
 {{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}}
```

Comment: more like CREATE TABLE foo(
 id bigserial NOT NULL, 
 l1 integer,
 l2 integer,
 l3 integer);

select my_aggregate(l1,l2,l3) from foo where blah blah group by bar

Comment: foo has a number of columns which i have omitted. any one of them could be bar.

Comment: @Gokul So you need bar to be the first element of the array?

Comment: I use bar only to select the groups of rows on which i need to apply the aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody encount some issue following erwin's great answer.
before postgresql 14 follow  Erwin's answer.
for postgresql 14, we need tiny tweak.

```
create or replace aggregate 
array_agg_mult(anycompatiblearray)
(sfunc = array_cat, 
stype = anycompatiblearray, 
initcond = '{}');
```