# How to aggregate two PostgreSQL columns to an array separated by brackets

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, concatenation, array-agg

I would like to concatenate two columns using a group-by query resulting in an array separed with brackets. I know this question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query) question, but as usual my use-case is a little different.

A simple example (also as [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e6ce0/28)).
Currently my query returns the following:

```
ID  X   Y
3   0.5 2.71
3   1.0 2.50
3   1.5 2.33
6   0.5 2.73
6   1.5 2.77
```

But where I would like concatenate/aggregate the `X`/`Y` columns to get the following:

```
ID  XY
3   [[0.5,2.71],[1.0,2.50],[1.5,2.33]]
6   [[0.5,2.73],[1.5,2.77]]
```

Currently I've tried to concatenate the columns into one as follows:

```
SELECT "ID",concat_ws(', ',"X", "Y") as XY FROM Table1;
```

Which returns:

```
ID  xy
3   0.5, 2.71
3   1, 2.50
3   1.5, 2.33
6   0.5, 2.73
```

And used `array_agg()`:

```
SELECT "ID",array_to_string(array_agg("X"),',') AS XY
FROM Table1
GROUP BY "ID";
```

Resulting in:

```
ID  xy
3   0.5,1,1.5
6   0.5
```

I feel I'm getting closer, but a helping hand would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Create an array from the two columns, the aggregate the array:

```
select id, array_agg(array[x,y])
from the_table
group by id;
```

Note that the default text representation of arrays uses curly braces ( `{..}`) not square brackets (`[..]`)

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond, it works perfect in postgresql (not in sqlfiddle)

Comment: @Mattijn: Your version is obviously 9.5 or later. sqlfiddle has been stuck at 9.3 for some time now.

Comment: Also, type of x and y should be same, i.e if x is of text, then y should also be  of type text. If not, need to use type case.(::text)

Answer (score 13):

In Postgres **9.5 or later** a overloaded variant of [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) takes *array* input as [provided by @a_horse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39213120/939860).

```
SELECT id, array_agg(ARRAY[x, y]) AS xy
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY id;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

> Concatenates all the input arrays into an array of one higher
> dimension. (The inputs must all have the same dimensionality, and
> cannot be empty or null.)

---

In **older versions**, this isn't implemented yet. You can create your own aggregate function (once per database) to achieve the same:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray)  (
    SFUNC     = array_cat
  , STYPE     = anyarray
  , INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

Then:

```
SELECT id, array_agg_mult(ARRAY[ARRAY[x,y]]) AS xy  -- note the 2D array!
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY id;
```

Details:

- [Selecting data into a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762398/selecting-data-into-a-postgres-array/11763245#11763245)

Or you can **concatenate a string**:

```
SELECT id, '[[' || string_agg(concat_ws(',', x, y), '],[') || ']]' AS xy
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY id;
```

Produces your desired result exactly. A string, not an array.