# Aggregating all values not in the same group

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to take this table:

| ID | country | name | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | John Smith | {1,2,3} |
| 2 | USA | Jane Smith | {0,1,3} |
| 3 | USA | Jane Doe | {1,1,1} |
| 4 | USA | John Doe | {0,2,4} |

and generate this table from it with the column `agg_values`:

| ID | country | name | values | agg_values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | John Smith | {1,2,3} | {0,1,3,1,1,1,0,2,4} |
| 2 | USA | Jane Smith | {0,1,3} | {1,2,3,1,1,1,0,2,4} |
| 3 | USA | Jane Doe | {1,1,1} | {1,2,3,0,1,3,0,2,4} |
| 4 | USA | John Doe | {0,2,4} | {1,2,3,0,1,3,1,1,1} |

Where each row aggregates all `values` except from the current row and its peers.
So if `name = John Smith` then `agg_values = aggregate of all values where name not = John Smith`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Postgres 11** or later, use a [**window function** with a custom frame and a **`frame_exclusion`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

```sql
SELECT *, array_combine(values) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                           AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                                           EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS agg_values
FROM   tbl;
```

If `name` is not `UNIQUE`, and since you asked:

> all values where name not = John Smith

```sql
SELECT *, array_combine(values) OVER (ORDER BY name
                                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                           AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                                           EXCLUDE GROUP) AS agg_values
FROM   tbl;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2b497459261b78f41929dede688d71e5)*

The first one (also) works with arbitrary order of rows, only excluding the current one. The second requires `ORDER BY` to establish which rows are in the same group.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)

> The `frame_exclusion` option allows rows around the current row to be
> excluded from the frame, even if they would be included according to
> the frame start and frame end options. **`EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW`
> excludes the current row from the frame. `EXCLUDE GROUP` excludes the
> current row and its ordering peers from the frame.** `EXCLUDE TIES`
> excludes any peers of the current row from the frame, but not the
> current row itself. [...]

Bold emphasis mine.

This uses the custom aggregate function `array_combine(anyarray)` [provided by a_horse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67976676/939860).
Or here:

- [Selecting data into a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762398/selecting-data-into-a-postgres-array/11763245#11763245)
- [Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays/12414884#12414884)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. It was greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join to a derived table that unnests all rows where the name is not equal and then aggregates that back into an array:

```
select t1.*, xu.agg_values
from the_table t1
  cross join lateral (
      select array_agg(tu.v) as agg_values
      from the_table t2
        cross join unnest(t2."values") as tu(v)
      where t2.name <> t1.name
  ) xu
```

This can be simplified by creating a custom aggregate to avoid the unnesting and aggregating:

```
create aggregate array_combine(anyarray)
(
  sfunc = array_cat(anyarray, anyarray),
  stype = anyarray
);
```

Then this can be written as:

```
select t1.*, xu.agg_values
from the_table t1
  cross join lateral (
      select array_combine(t2.values) as agg_values
      from the_table t2
      where t2.name <> t1.name
  ) xu
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. It was greatly appreciated!