# Find greatest and least column values in a sliding window frame

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Coming from procedural programming, I am thinking of a loop to solve this. Example logic:

- Sort by `column1` value and date column descending. Query similar to:

```
select * 
from table1 
where column1 in ('cpu1') 
order by date_time desc;
```

- Find the last row from the select query as well as the row 22 lines above it to define the loop start point for the first set of data to review. i do not have the rows serialized currently but know the time will be 5 minutes between each row entry so I could use the timestamp to determine 22 rows. I think the query looks something like:

```
select * 
from table1 
where date_time between x and y;
```

- find the 10th row in the data selected in the between statement and determine if column2 in the 10th row is greater than all 12 rows above and all 9 rows below based or column 3 10th row is less than 12 rows above and 9 rows below. If it is greater or less than print 10th row to a new table.

I don't have anything for this query yet because I'm not understanding how to navigate table indexing in the fashion you might with Javascript arrays or Python dictionaries.

- increment x, y and 10th row values -1 and run loop again.

**The problem**

I'm struggling with understanding how to put a PostgreSQL script together. I've designed similar style loops with Python or Javascript but the more I read about possible ways to go about it in SQL the more confused I'm getting. Is the most optimal way to do this CTE, for, while or a cursor?

Example table data:

| column1 | column2 | column3 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cpu1 | 3.2 | 1.1 | 01:45:00 |
| cpu1 | 3.5 | 1.3 | 01:40:00 |
| cpu1 | 5.9 | 0.1 | 01:35:00 |
| cpu1 | 1.7 | 1.2 | 01:30:00 |
| cpu1 | 2.5 | 2.3 | 01:25:00 |
| cpu1 | 5.2 | 4.1 | 01:20:00 |
| cpu3 | 4.2 | 1.1 | 01:45:00 |
| cpu3 | 3.1 | 1.0 | 01:40:00 |
| cpu3 | 5.0 | 3.3 | 01:35:00 |
| cpu3 | 4.7 | 3.2 | 01:30:00 |
| cpu3 | 2.7 | 2.1 | 01:25:00 |
| cpu3 | 6.2 | 4.8 | 01:20:00 |

- `column1` will be device names that write time series to the database
- `column2` and `column3` will be recorded values from the device
- date will always be in 5 minute increments
- The table1 has millions of rows

Comment: You'll want to look up "window functions" and assuming there are no gaps in the timestamp, you can do this without looping by referring to an element as a relative 10th position away. You'd probably accomplish this by doing a MAX() OVER the prior 12 rows and compare that to the current row

Comment: thank you for helping me with a starting point

Comment: Whenever you're looking at an SQL problem and thinking "loop" (or "cursor"), you're almost certainly thinking about the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: I need to compare each row of time series data to x number of consecutive rows above and y number of consecutive rows below for a match of being greater than or less than. Window functions with lead/lag seem to be part of the answer. Do you have a recommendation of how to work the problem differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented elegantly and efficiently with window functions:

For all devices:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *, col2 > max(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY device ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 9 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW)
          OR col3 < min(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY device ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 9 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS bingo
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE  bingo;
```

For a single given device:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , col2 > max(col2) OVER (ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 9 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) OR
          col3 < min(col3) OVER (ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 9 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS bingo
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  device = 'cpu3'
   ) sub
WHERE  bingo;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dlZodFhj)

Assuming all columns are defined `NOT NULL`, and the timestamp (`ts` in my query) is also `UNIQUE` per device. Or you have to define how to deal with null values and duplicates in the sort order.

This uses a whole arsenal of advanced window function features. The "frame exclusion" option `EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW` requires **Postgres 11** or later. [Read the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) Related:

- [Aggregating all values not in the same group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67975901/aggregating-all-values-not-in-the-same-group/67979056#67979056)

Not an easy task if you are accustomed to procedural languages.

Comment: Thank you for the time it took to write your code and response. Having this to review and work with actually taught me a lot in a short amount of time.